# Make UIPageViewController not be covered by a toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitoolbar, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that is in a container view which contains a UIToolbar on the bottom.

[image: bottom toolbar]

Currently the toolbar covers all views that are at the bottom of the view controller that the UIPageViewController is showing.

[image: from user interface inspector]

I can inset the frame of the UIPageViewController but then you can't see the blurred child view under the toolbar. Is there a way to inset the view so it will make the child constraints relative to the top of toolbar, but still be able to see the view underneath the toolbar?